# Features code changes overriding automatically

Tags: features

I have a panels page in Features but as soon as i change the Features code, it automatically overrides the DB, this means that i don't get to see the "Overridden" state grey button, but always the normal "Default" state is shown and the changes are automatically shown on the web page.

The features should not change automatically the code, but only after i choose to override them.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I thought that was an UUID problem, but after removing the UUID module, the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is how Features work. If your feature is in `Default` state, code change will cause direct effect on the components (there are some exceptions when clear cache is required). This is actually one of the biggest points and benefits of features, you can easily deploy updated code without any further required action.

Maybe there is a problem with your workflow, you should create you features on you Dev environment (configurations etc), then export them and deploy to Stage/Prod. It is not a good practice to directly change the configuration of components on Stage/Prod environments, you should always do your changes on Dev, then recreate the feature and deploy.

Comment: I do have that workflow, but sometimes editors change content (of the "featured" panels page) on Prod and I would have thought (and think it was happening before at some stage) that importing the DB (and files) to a local deploy, would keep the same scenario as Prod: overridden features. So that I can easily recreate locally a new version of the feature, put it in version control, then push to prod again. This is not happening, so I will need to recreate the editor's changes manually on my local website, re-create the overridden state locally, then re-create the feature and push to the repo.

Comment: The issue is something else then, of course that when you import the DB with overrides to you local machine you should see the same overrides. Are you sure that your export/import DB procedure is ok and that your local site is using the correct newly imported production DB? E.g. all new content is present etc.?

Comment: You are right, I have noticed that some parts of the DB are not getting synced when I drush sql-sync with Prod. For example, a content page didn't get imported... I wonder what could that be. I will consider to remove this question. Any ideas what could cause this strange behaviour?

Comment: try doing it manually (mysql dump and import)